# Updating the entire column in table when change of one value occured in same table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am very new to PL/SQL programming and I faced a problem with solving this:

**Problem Statement:**

→ EMPLOYEE_PAY Table has columns (ID, NAME, LOCATION, BASIC_SALARY, NET_SALARY).

A company has a policy of same basic salary for all the employees, but net salary changes based on performance of an employee. So, the Basic Salary column must always bare same value. The requirements are

1. If an employee's basic salary is changed by an Insert or Update, the
   basic salary column should assume the new value as the main value
   and the column is to be updated with the latest basic salary.
2. When the basic salary column is updated, the values of net salary
   for each employee should also be updated accordingly in the main
   table.

The net salary can be updated as-

**New net salary = new basic salary * (old net salary / old basic salary)**

Ex:
`EMPLOYEE TABLE
ID      NAME         LOCATION    BASIC_SALARY   NET_SALARY`
***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**
`12102   John         Bangalore         10000        25450
12155   Rana         Hyderabad         10000        24500
12154   Kejriwal     New Delhi         10000        25500
12553   Narendra     Patna             10000        25250`

Assume, If a value is inserted into this table or updated with basic salary as 12000, the table should look like this updating the basic salary and net salary:

`EMPLOYEE TABLE
ID      NAME        LOCATION   BASIC_SALARY   NET_SALARY`
***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**
`12102   John        Bangalore         12000        30540
12155   Rana        Hyderabad         12000        29400
12154   Kejriwal    New Delhi         12000        30600
12553   Narendra    Patna             12000        30300
12455   Sachin      Mumbai            12000        30500`

Note: This Entire process needs to be performed on Oracle DB, using triggers in PL/SQL.

The main problem I face is 'how to change previous record values using triggers while working on one record?' - as 'triggers deals with one row at a time' (From the knowledge I had about triggers as of now)

The code I have tired to do this till now is as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_PAY(
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR(20),
  LOCATION CHAR(25),
  BASIC_SALARY DECIMAL(18,2),
  NET_SALARY DECIMAL(18,2),
  PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_BASIC_PAY
BEFORE INSERT ON EMPLOYEE_PAY
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE EMPLOYEE_PAY
  SET BASIC_SALARY = :NEW.BASIC_SALARY
  WHERE BASIC_SALARY != :NEW.BASIC_SALARY;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_NET_PAY
BEFORE UPDATE OF BASIC_SALARY ON EMPLOYEE_PAY
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE EMPLOYEE_PAY
  SET NET_SALARY = :NEW.BASIC_SALARY * (:OLD.NET_SALARY/:OLD.BASIC_SALARY)
  WHERE BASIC_SALARY != :NEW.BASIC_SALARY;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;
```

When I tried this, in the result set the basic salary got updated only for `INSERT INTO` and net salary remained unchanged. Please help me out with possible solutions as soon as possible.

Thank you

Comment: Your database model is fundamentally flawed. This is not the way you should do it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: your data model is not good, as you certainly notice yourself. If the basic salary is the same for all employees, why store it redundantly per employee?  If the net salary is the basic salary times a factor, why store the result rather than the factor? If you just changed your data model then you would have no problem at all.

If you must stay with your model, here are my remarks concerning your triggers:

1. In your insert trigger you only update basic_salary and in your update trigger you only update net_salary. This is not what you want. You want to update both fields in both triggers. (You can make this one combined insert/update trigger though).
2. :OLD values apply to the record that is being inserted or updated. But you should work with the values of the record you are calculating for.
3. Apply the changes AFTER your insert or update, as you don't want to change the record being inserted or updated, but all records.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_PAY_CORRECTION
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF BASIC_SALARY ON EMPLOYEE_PAY
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      UPDATE EMPLOYEE_PAY
      SET
        BASIC_SALARY = :NEW.BASIC_SALARY,
        NET_SALARY = NET_SALARY * :NEW.BASIC_SALARY / BASIC_SALARY
      WHERE BASIC_SALARY != :NEW.BASIC_SALARY;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
    END;
```

Comment: I agree: the model is fundamentally flawed and should be re-designed rather than working around the *real* problem by applying some hack through triggers.